# PyCharm: conflicting file is displaying as a normal file

Tags: git, pycharm, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

The problem is that after some commits into different branches, I've got a merging conflict.

I decided to resolve it via PyCharm, but VCS->Git->Resolve Conflicts is disabled.

After, I looked into Local changes and the file with conflicts is `blue` instead of `red`.

What is going on and how to resolve my conflicts with PyCharm?

Btw, There are a lot of `<<< HEAD` parts in this file, as expected.

UPDATE:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/test' by 50 commits.
   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not stated for commit:
    (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git checkout -- <file>..."  to discard changes in working directory)

        modified: directory/subdirectory/filename

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Looks like you did something unintended after the merge conflict occurred. Could you add which action caused the conflict (merge, rebase, pull) and what the output of `git status` is?

Comment: The conflict occurred after `pull`.Git status shows that file with conflict has changed.

Comment: Please copy the exact output to your question. This helps us a lot to understand the current state. You can change filenames if you don't want us to know them.

Comment: @AmShaegar, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something went wrong. IDEs can sometimes do magic things if you accidentally press the wrong button.

I'd go like this:

1. Reset your current working directory back to your last local revision:

   `git reset --hard HEAD`
2. Redo the pull to get the conflict marker back.

   `git pull`

You should now be able to solve conflicts in your IDE.

Comment: Didn't reset remove my local changes?

Comment: This removes all uncommitted changes, yes. But as far as I understand you just pulled. So there shouldn't be any changes apart from the ones, the merge is causing.

Comment: Another thing that just came to my mind: Did you accidentally commit that file earlier with the conflict markers?